# Updating the View with Model changes via Ajax Post by calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-core, http-post

I use an Ajax call to update my model value and then have that new value should be shown in the view. Here is my code . In this code I am calling a method GetText and updating model value. How can I show the new model value in the html. Please help

```
public class EmpModel
{
public string EmpClaim {get;set;}
}


 public IActionResult EmpClaim()
 {
    return View();
 }
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetText(EmpModel model)
    {
        model.EmpClaim = "New Text" // This should be shown in view

         return Json(data);

    }
```

Html file

```
@model Test.Models.EmpModel
<div>
<input type="text" name="Claim" class="form-control" id="TxtClaim"  asp-for="Claim" data-role="text"/>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeText()" id="changeButton"  />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
 function changeText()
{
 var url = '@Url.Action("GetText", "EmpDoc")';
    $.post(url, $('form').serialize(), function (view) {
        $("#TxtClaim").val(); // How can I update the TxtClim with model.EmpClaim "New Text" 
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `return Content()` to return string to ajax function.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetText(EmpModel model)
    { 
       model.EmpClaim = "New Text" // This should be shown in view  
        return Content(model.EmpClaim); 
    }
```

Js:

```
 <script>
     function changeText()
     {
     var url = '@Url.Action("GetText", "EmpDoc")';
        $.post(url, $('form').serialize(), function (view) {
            $("#TxtClaim").val(view); // How can I update the TxtClim with model.EmpClaim "New Text"
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

**Note**:

In your case, the model does not have `a key field`, so when you update the data, you cannot determine which piece of data to update. Further operations may require you to modify the model design.

You can refer to [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/create-edit-view-in-asp.net-mvc).